# How to load devIL image from raw data

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, textures, devil

I would like to create devIL image from raw texture data, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. The proper way seems to be ilLoadL with IL_RAW, but I can't get it to work. The documentation in [here](http://www-f9.ijs.si/~matevz/docs/DevIL/il/f00152.htm) says that that there should be 13-byte header in the data, so i just put meaningless data there. If I put 0 to "size" parameter of ilLoadL,
I'll get black texture, no matter what. Otherwise my program refuses to draw anything. ilIsImage returns true, and I can create openGL texture from it just fine. The code works if I load texture from file.

It's not much, but here's my code so far:

```
    //Loading:
    ilInit();
    iluInit();

    ILuint ilID;


    ilGenImages(1, &ilID);

    ilBindImage(ilID);

    ilEnable(IL_ORIGIN_SET);
    ilOriginFunc(IL_ORIGIN_LOWER_LEFT);


        //Generate 13-byte header and fill it with meaningless numbers
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i){

            data.insert(data.begin() + i, i);
        }


    //This fails.
    if (!ilLoadL(IL_RAW, &data[0], size)){
        std::cout << "Fail" << std::endl;
    }
```

Texture creation:

```
        ilBindImage(ilId[i]);

        ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

        glBindTexture(textureTarget, id[i]);

        glTexParameteri(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
        glTexParameteri(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);

        glTexParameterf(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filters[i]);
        glTexParameterf(textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filters[i]);

        glTexImage2D(textureTarget, 0, GL_RGBA,
            ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH), ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT),
            0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ilGetData());
```

Answer (score 2):

If an image format has a header, you can generally assume it contains some important information necessary to correctly read the rest of the file. Filling it with *"meaningless data"* is inadvisable at best.

Since there is no actual `struct` in DevIL for the `.raw` header, let us take a look at the implementation of `iLoadRawInternal ()` to figure out what those first 13-bytes are supposed to be.

```c
// Internal function to load a raw image
ILboolean iLoadRawInternal()
{
    if (iCurImage == NULL) {
        ilSetError(IL_ILLEGAL_OPERATION);
        return IL_FALSE;
    }    

    iCurImage->Width = GetLittleUInt();   /* Bytes: 0-3   {Image Width}     */
    iCurImage->Height = GetLittleUInt();  /* Bytes: 4-7   {Image Height}    */
    iCurImage->Depth = GetLittleUInt();   /* Bytes: 8-11  {Image Depth}     */
    iCurImage->Bpp = (ILubyte)igetc();    /* Byte:  12    {Bytes per-pixel} */
```

<sup>**NOTE**: *The `/* comments */` are my own*</sup>

`GetLittleUInt ()` reads a 32-bit unsigned integer in little-endian order and advances the read location appropriately. `igetc ()` does the same for a single byte.

#### This is equivalent to the following C structure (minus the byte order consideration):

```c
struct RAW_HEADER {
  uint32_t width;
  uint32_t height;
  uint32_t depth;  // This is depth as in the number of 3D slices (not bit depth)
  uint8_t  bpp;    // **Bytes** per-pixel (1 = Luminance, 3 = RGB, 4 = RGBA)
};
```

If you read the rest of the implementation of `iLoadRawInternal ()` in `il_raw.c`, you will see that without proper values in the header DevIL will not be able to calculate the correct file size. Filling in the correct values should help.